# Ansible playbooks - Adding a secret with Boolean value to HashiCorp vault

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault

I am using the Ansible playbook to add a secret to the HashiCorp vault, if the secret does not exist. the problem is, that is adding {"active": "false"}, instead of {"active": false}

Code:

```
- name: Check if secret already exists in Vault
  shell: "vault kv get secret/proxy_servers"
  environment:
    VAULT_TOKEN: "{{ vault_token.stdout }}"
  register: secret_output
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Add proxy details secret to vault if it does not exist
  shell: "vault kv put secret/proxy_servers active=false"
  environment:
    VAULT_TOKEN: "{{ vault_token.stdout }}"
  when: secret_output.rc != 0
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the exact error message?

Comment: No error. It adds {"active": "false"}, instead of {"active": false}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the `key=value` syntax on the `vault kv write` command line, there's no way for the CLI to know that you mean the boolean value `false` instead of the string value `false`. You can only specify string values using this syntax. If you want to write other values, feed `vault kv put` a JSON document on stdin like this:

```
vault kv put secret/proxy_servers - <<EOF
{"active": false}
EOF
```

In your playbook, this might look like:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Check if secret already exists in Vault
      command: "vault kv get secret/proxy_servers"
      register: secret_output
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Add proxy details secret to vault if it does not exist
      command: "vault kv put secret/proxy_servers -"
      args:
        stdin: |
          {"active": false}
      when: secret_output.rc != 0
```

Or you could use the `vault_read` and `vault_write` modules from the `community.hashi_vault` collection:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
    - community.hashi_vault
  tasks:
    - name: Check if secret already exists in Vault
      vault_read:
        path: secret/data/proxy_servers
      register: proxy_servers
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Add proxy details secret to vault if it does not exist
      when: proxy_servers is failed
      vault_write:
        path: secret/data/proxy_servers
        data:
          data:
            active: false
```